# Drop a word and a dot at the start of a data.frame columnames using BASE R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, character

Using BASE R, I was wondering how to remove `"tlist."` from the start of the column names in: `nms = data.frame(tlist.time_wk = 1:5, tlist.treats = 2:6, bb = 3:7)`?

Desired output:

```
data.frame(time_wk = 1:5, treats = 2:6, bb = 3:7)
```

Comment: `names(nms) <- sub('^tlist\\.', '', names(nms))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use gsub to edit the names attribute. Not sure, though, if this counts as base R?
Use '\\' in front of the dot to remove a literal dot

```
names(nms) <- gsub("^tlist\\.", "", names(nms))
```

edit: this IS base R, added '^' to only capture from the beginning of the strings

Comment: Upvote but, why wouldn't this count as base R?

Comment: It is found in the base package, see ?gsub. BTW, no `gsub` needed, `sub` is enough here.

Comment: I updated the answer, thanks tpetzoldt. Rui: i was just mentining that I wasn't sure. In my world, everything regarding dataframes which is not data.table or dplyr is base. But that might be simplifying things.

Answer (score 2):

You can also extract what you need -

```
names(nms) <- sub('^tlist\\.(.*)', '\\1', names(nms))
names(nms)
#[1] "time_wk" "treats"  "bb"
```